# a code from jsfiddle doesn't work locally

Tags: jsfiddle

I need your help. The following code is a copy of a code in jsfiddle.(https://jsfiddle.net/atfLe15b)

In jsfiddle it works but the following code in my computer doesn't work.

More details, In jsfiddle show all file list in the folder. but in my computer it show only the folder name.

Anybody knows about this? thank you in advance.

here is the code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>ExampleEdit</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
            <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
            <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
                #dropzone {
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 100px;
                    margin: 10px;
                    padding: 10px;
                    border: 4px dashed red;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }    
                #boxtitle {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    text-align: center;
                    color: black;
                    font: bold 2em "Arial", sans-serif;
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 100px;
                }    
                body {
                    font: 14px "Arial", sans-serif;
                }
            </style>    
            <script id="insert"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Drag files and/or directories to the box below!</p>    
            <div id="dropzone">
                <div id="boxtitle">
                    Drop Files Here
                </div>
            </div>    
            <h2>Directory tree:</h2>    
            <ul id="listing">
            </ul>    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                let dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
                let listing = document.getElementById("listing");
    
                function scanFiles(item, container) {
                    let elem = document.createElement("li");
                    elem.innerHTML = item.name;
                    container.appendChild(elem);
    
                    if (item.isDirectory) {
                        let directoryReader = item.createReader();
                        let directoryContainer = document.createElement("ul");
                        container.appendChild(directoryContainer);
    
                directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                            entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                                scanFiles(entry, directoryContainer);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
                dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }, false);
                dropzone.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
                    let items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    
                    event.preventDefault();
                    listing.innerHTML = "";
    
                    for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                        let item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    
                        if (item) {
                            scanFiles(item, listing);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me!
try to change your file name to *.html (index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /js/lib/dummy.js and /css/result-light.css files.